# Suggestions for clustering ordinal, non-normal data (unsupervised)

Tags: r, clustering, multivariate-analysis

I have data from about 250 self-injurers and would like to cluster analyze their reported motivations for self injury (and then explore cluster membership vis-a-vis various psychological measures). I have scores on 9 motivation scales which are likert-type but non-normal ($\log_{10}$-transformations yield <1 skewness for maybe 5 of the scales but 3 remain greater than 2 --as many participants only endorse one or two motivation types and give 0's on the other scales). 
I understand that some algorithms are more robust against normality violations and I have been reading about possible routines to use in `R` including DBSCAN, MClust, and EMMIX but am struggling to wrap my mind around a best approach. Density vs. similarity approaches etc. I understand that DBSCAN struggles as dimensions increase: are 9 variables a concern for this approach?. I can live with losing cases as 'noise' and even non-exclusive cluster membership (though am less excited about that outcome). Any thoughts/references are most appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

DBSCAN in the default setup needs just a dissimilarity matrix.

At 9 dimensions, even Euclidean distance should still work reasonably, and there are many other dissimilarity functions to choose from.

So why don't you just give DBSCAN a try?

The first thing to do is to choose an appropriate similarity for your problem, then determine the threshold you consider "similar".

Comment: Excellent. Thanks very much for the suggestion Anony-Mousse. I'm reading up on setting Eps and Minpts as I've not done density clustering before. It helps to have a direction to move in. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The issue of normality is not relevant to clustering and, at the expense of making up some data, 99.9999% of likert-type scales do not look normal.  Indeed, if all the variables were normal it would suggest that clustering was perhaps not even relevant.

The "standard" approach to this problem is to use k-means cluster analysis and pretend that the ordinal data is really numeric.  This is the approach used in most market segmentation studies and if you look at the marketing and market research academic literatures you will find many hundreds of such applications.  If you have not analyzed data of the type you are looking at before I'd suggest you do a bit of a search on market segmentation as it is basically the same problem that you are trying to solve.

If you want to be a bit more scientific, you can fit a latent class model that explicitly addresses the ordinal nature of the data.  I am not sure if this is available in any R package.  Two commercial packages which have solutions explicitly developed for this are:

- [Latent Gold](http://statisticalinnovations.com/products/latentgold.html)
- [Q](http://www.q-researchsoftware.com)